# Ionic Cordova InAppBrowser doesn't open the url a second time

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

I have this code in my app. I am trying to load urls using InAppBrowser. It works perfectly when the url is loaded the first time. The second time, the browser simply doesn't open for the same url or a different url. What is happening here?

I am wondering if this is because an instance of InAppBrowser is still running and needs to be forcefully closed. If so, can I force the browser to close if I detect and instance of it?

```js
let options = 'location=yes';
this.browser = this.iab.create(url, "_system", options);
```

Opening the browser as "_blank" or "_self" doesn't open the browser at all.

Comment: What os are you trying this on? Check if  the new page load on the old “open” browser.

Comment: Mayank, I am trying this on android right now. I am yet to test it on ios. How to load a new url on the existing browser?

Comment: When you use _system, you open the system browser (usually Chrome). Are you going back to the app before trying to call open again? because when you load Chrome your app loses the focus and the javascript stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the html part. The source element was anchor. When I changed the source element to button, the application started working as expected.